# Call to PageMethods in WebForm returns 404 in MVC project

Tags: model-view-controller, webforms, http-status-code-404

I am trying to add a WebForm to an MVC project to see if the code can be reused.  Inside the WebForm, the JavaScript call to PageMethods returns failure:

> The server method '*{my pagemethod}*' failed

There is no stack trace, the HTTP status code is 404 and the status text is null.

The page was working in the WebForm project and I confirmed that the parameters were passed correctly to the PageMethods call.

Is there something to expose the PageMethods of WebForm in an MVC project?

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP 404 is caused by the page not being found.

Adding the following line to the RouteConfig solved the issue:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: +1.  In my case, I had [modified a .NET 4 WebForms project to enable MVC side-by-side](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx).  When calling `PageMethods` in my JS the URL resolution was going through RouteConfig processing and producing the wrong URL, hence a 404.  By adding the above `IgnoreRoute` line at the top of my RouteConfig it worked perfectly.